# Reply Comment System

Tags: php, mysql, comments, review, reply

Hello Everyone I am new to php and doing a project. My Problem is I am working on review page and fetching data from 3 tables using while loop.

The problem is I want to create comment reply system. I am using text area for comment in loop and showing the text area on button click but when I am click on button, each text area gets visible which I don't want. I think problem is due to while loop.
Please suggest me a proper idea.
Thank u in advance.

Php part:

```
<div class="feedback-list">

                                                                                <!--img class="doc-img"src="img/doc-img.png" alt="tempimg"   height="100"                 width="100"/>
    <div class="feedback-header"-->              
          <?php
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
             {
                $username1=$row1['username'];
                $rtitle=$row1['reviewtitle'];
                 $rexperience=$row1['experience'];

                                 echo '<div  class="feedback"><img class="doc-img" src="img/doc-img.png" alt="temp img" height="100" width="100"/><div class="feedback-header">Rivew by <a href="#"> '.$username1.'</a>
                                <span class="stars" id="star1"><img src="img/stars.png"/></span>
                            </div>
                            <p> '.$rtitle.'</p><br/>
                            <p> '.$rexperience.'</p>



                                                                        <form action="submitcomment.php"  method="post" name="frms">
            <!--button type="submit" onclick="showCommentBox()">Reply</button><br/-->
          <input type="button" value="Reply" onclick="showCommentBox('.$row1['reviewid'].')"><br/>
          <div class="hidden" id="comment">
            <!--p>Comments and suggestions:<br><textarea name="comments" rows="3" cols="30" ></textarea><br><br>
              <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Confirm"></p-->
            </div>
            </form>



                            <span class="read-more">Read      More</span>
                            <span class="added-by">added on 25 March</span>
                        </div>';}?>
```

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function showCommentBox(x){
          //alert(x);
         var div=document.getElementById('comment');

         div.className='visible';

         document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML =
   '<br/><textarea maxlength="5000" cols="30" rows="3" name="comments"></textarea>' + 
   '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Confirm">';
          }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the textarea with `id="comment"`? I don't see it. **Please** indent your code properly. It's a mess right now.

Answer (score 0):

**ALL** of your comment boxes have the same DOM ID:

```
  <div class="hidden" id="comment">
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is not permitted. An ID must be unique across the entire page. Because of this, `getElementById()` will only ever return ONE element which matches, which is generally the FIRST matching element it finds - there is no point in continuing to search for something of which only one can exist, right?

You probably want something more like

```
 <div class="hidden" id="comment{$id}">

 <button onclick="showComment($id);" >



 function showComment(id) {
     foo = document.getElementById('comment' + id);
 }
```